# How do you derive symmetries of algebraic equations? Do they relate to the solutions?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, symmetry

Let's take for example $x^2 + y^2 = 1.$ This has infinitely many symmetries, but a portion of those symmetries have the form $(x,y) \rightarrow (x \cos(\epsilon) - y \sin( \epsilon), x \sin( \epsilon) + y \cos( \epsilon))$ for $\epsilon \in [-\pi, \pi].$

My questions are: how do you derive such symmetries for algebraic equations and systems of algebraic equations, and, do these symmetries relate to their solutions in any way?

Comment: You'd need to clarify what it is you mean by a 'symmetry'

Comment: A smooth transformation which leaves the original manifold invariant.

Comment: This is too large a definition: this would in particular allow pure change of parameters like for your circle example $(\cos(t),\sin(t)) \to (\cos(f(t)),\sin(f(t)))$

Comment: Okay, so what's wrong with that?